# Calling Helper Method from partial view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, helper

In my bar.html I render a partial view and in it I want to call the method foo(var1, var2) and get an array back. On my local system everything works finde but on my production system the following error occurs.

```
undefined local variable or method `foo' for #<#<Class:0x70c6410>:0x706f480>)
```

Can someone explain this to me?

The Class #<#:0x706f480> changes with every call so it seems that the view does not try to search the function in my helper.

EDIT:

The application has the following structure (example)

```
app/helpers/bar_helper
app/views/bar/bar.html.erb
app/views/bar/partials/bar_partial.html.erb
```

and in bar_partial.html.erb I call foo(var1, var2) in my bar_helper like this

```
<% data = foo(var1, var2) %>
```

Comment: where is your foo method is defined .. can you share some code that you wrote.

Comment: see the edit part, unfortunately I cannot share the code =/

Comment: does the helper call work from the main view in production ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, that the class existed a second time somewhere in the folder structure so that ruby found the first file and used that one instead of the right one.